# javascript:apex.navigation.redirect not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oracle-apex

I'm using apex dynamic action to execute javascript code:

```js
apex.navigation.redirect('f?p=&APP_ID.:6006:&SESSION.:::6006:P6006_NAZIV:'+apex.item("P0_SEARCH").getValue());
```

It is redirecting to page 6006 and send the value of page item P0_SEARCH to page 6006, to item P6006_NAZIV.

It's working fine on firefox browser, but not on Chrome, what can be the problem?

Comment: Dynamic action is on change event of global page, when I hit enter on firefox it's works, but on chrome enter key only submit current page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using application process (redirect_url), on submit-before computations and validations.